# Understanding ActiveMQ Artemis AMQ222061 & AMQ222107 warnings

Tags: spring-jms, activemq-artemis

Currently I am receiving very low traffic to my application 1-2 req/sec which are sent to an JMS queue. However in the `artemis.log` I am seeing the following `WARN` messages.

```
2021-06-23 10:51:49,433 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222061: Client connection failed, clearing up resources for session d798a4d3-d3f7-11eb-86d7-005056b536f0
2021-06-23 10:51:49,434 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222107: Cleared up resources for session d798a4d3-d3f7-11eb-86d7-005056b536f0
2021-06-23 10:51:49,434 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222061: Client connection failed, clearing up resources for session d798cbe4-d3f7-11eb-86d7-005056b536f0
2021-06-23 10:51:49,435 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222107: Cleared up resources for session d798cbe4-d3f7-11eb-86d7-005056b536f0
```

The Artemis journal is backed by NFS, and all messages are persisted. I am using Spring's `JmsTemplate` with a `JmsPoolConnectionFactory`.

```java
@Bean
public ConnectionFactory jmsConnectionFactoryOnline() {
    ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(brokerUrl,username,password);
    connectionFactory.setCallTimeout(3000);
    return connectionFactory;
}
```

```java
@Bean
@Primary
public JmsPoolConnectionFactory pooledConnectionFactory() {
    JmsPoolConnectionFactory poolingFactory = new JmsPoolConnectionFactory();
    poolingFactory.setConnectionFactory(jmsConnectionFactoryOnline());
    poolingFactory.setMaxConnections(8);
    poolingFactory.setMaxSessionsPerConnection(20);
    poolingFactory.setConnectionIdleTimeout(0);
    return poolingFactory;
}
```

Any ideas why there so many disconnects (they repeat every ~15 minutes) and how to debug it?

At client level I get the below warning but 3 seconds seems to much since the broker is up and accepting other messages:

```
23-06-2021 09:33:15 [Thread-24 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads)] [WARN ] org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client - AMQ212037: Connection failure to XXXXXX:61616 has been detected: AMQ219014: Timed out after waiting 3,000 ms for response when sending packet 71 [code=CONNECTION_TIMEDOUT]
```

**EDIT**

I have taken a thread dump every 3 sec. Check [here](https://fastthread.io/my-thread-report.jsp?p=c2hhcmVkLzIwMjEvMDYvMjQvLS10aHJlYWR1bXBzLnppcC0tMTMtMTAtNQ==) for relative information.

Monitoring the push to queue latency I can clearly see that with 1 req/sec I have spikes of latency whereas with 20 req/sec push to queue latencies seem normal as observed in the image below.

[Push to Queue latency](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D20IZ.png)

Also from tcpdump I can see that there is a pause between client and broker. There seems to be no traffic exchanged between them.
Therefore as soon as the callTimeout period has elapsed the client closes the connection.

[tcpdump](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4XTHj.png)

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to tell *why* there are so many disconnections with the information you've provided, but here are some debugging ideas:

- Get thread dumps from the broker to see if it's busy during the time around the disconnections.
- Turn on GC logging to ensure that long pauses are not causing the broker to be unresponsive.
- Turn on TRACE logging for `org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.RemotingConnectionImpl`. See the ActiveMQ Artemis [documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/logging.html#activating-trace-for-a-specific-logger) for details on how to configure that. This will let you see the incoming `PING` packets from clients or the absence thereof. When the broker doesn't receive pings within the configured connection TTL then it will close the client's connection.
- Monitor network resources for problems like delays, dropped packets, disconnections, etc.

Comment: Hi Justin, thanks for the quick response. I have edited my question with further information

Comment: Originally you asked, "Any ideas why there so many disconnects (they repeat every ~15 minutes) and how to debug it?" I addressed both of these questions in my answer. However, you followed up by taking some of my debugging ideas and providing that information in the question. *Each* of these bits of information could be presented and analyzed in their own question.

Comment: Thanks I provided information because the lack of it did not help answer "why there are so many disconnects". I can open a new question if this is more clear. However seeing steps taken could help others with similar situations

Comment: I think you should create one or more new questions to deal with this new information as this is now a much different question than the one you started with. To be clear, any new question should be *specifically* about some debugging info. If you just throw out a bunch of thread dumps or TCP dumps or screenshots and ask "what does this mean?" your question is likely to get closed.